# ffmpeg convert AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP in c++

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk, opus

I want to encode and decode the sound from my Android app to the Opus format using FFmpeg 4.2.2.

The problem is that my Android app provides a raw PCM sound in `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` format, but the FFmpeg opus encoder requires only `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP`. So, I decided to resample the sound using FFmpeg `swr_convert()` function but it crashes with `SIGSEGV` error and I can't understand why.

My code looks like this:

```
swrContext = swr_alloc();

av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_channel_layout", (int64_t) codecContext->channel_layouts, 0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_channel_layout", (int64_t) codecContext->channel_layouts,  0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_sample_rate", 8000, 0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_sample_rate", 48000, 0);

av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "in_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);
av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP,  0);

swr_init(swrContext);

memcpy(frame->data[0], data, dataSize); 

uint8_t *outBuffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * frame->nb_samples);

swr_convert(swrContext, &outBuffer, frame->nb_samples, (const uint8_t **)frame->data, frame->nb_samples);
```

I am new to C++ so sorry for some mistakes if I made them.

Comment: You are only allocating 1 byte to outBuffer. And swr_convert is writing much more than that.

Comment: thank you, but how I can allocate enough bytes? I don't have much knowledge in c++, but I assume I need to allocate count of bytes equal to frame->nb_samples, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @szatmary I updated my answer, but still get SIGSEGV (address access protected) error, I also tried to allocate much more bytes for outBuffer e.g. 1000 and 100000, but result the same, what I do wrong?

Comment: @easy_breezy: Is `frameEncode->data` an array of pointers? You're filling the first index in this call: `memcpy(frameEncode->data[0], data, dataSize);` but in `swr_convert` you're passing as `(const uint8_t **)frame->data`. I believe it should be `&frameEncode->data[0]`. Also, there are two identifiers `frameEncode` and `frame` that looks like multiple typos. Can you verify and update those? Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587839/libswresample-swr-convert-not-producing-enough-samples).

Comment: @Azeem, thanks for your advice, I'll try it tomorrow, also I corrected and updated my answer

Comment: @easy_breezy: No problem! Check this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/c4sKXG). You need to fill in the channels info and test it. One thing which is not clear here is the memory of `frame->data` in call `memcpy(frame->data[0], data, dataSize);`. Its memory should be enough for the contents to be copied from `data`. You need to make sure of that.

Comment: @Azeem I tried the code from the snippet and it works! Now I succeeded in resampling audio, but the sound after decoding has a very poor quality it's some kind of very illegible robo voice and I don't understand why

Comment: @easy_breezy: Awesome! That's progress! You can tinker with `out_sample_rate` to test it with different rates. I'd suggest converting from the command line first using `ffmpeg` command, evaluate the quality of the output file and then fill in the parameters that you think would be good. See this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/239356/784747) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854513/can-ffmpeg-convert-audio-to-raw-pcm-if-so-how) one too. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things that you need to take care of:

Make sure that the `frame->data[0]` contains enough memory (at least equal to `dataSize`) for the `data` to be copied from in this call:

```
memcpy( frame->data[0], data, dataSize );
```

Also, you need to set `frame->nb_samples` accordingly. Maybe, you already have but there's no indication in the code that you have posted.

You also need to allocate samples buffer using `av_samples_alloc` and free it including all the other allocated memory after use so that there won't be any memory leaks.

Here's an example (add the value for `out_num_channels`):

```
const int in_sample_rate = 8000;
const int out_sample_rate = 48000;

swrContext = swr_alloc();
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_channel_layout", (int64_t) codecContext->channel_layouts, 0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_channel_layout", (int64_t) codecContext->channel_layouts,  0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_sample_rate", in_sample_rate, 0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_sample_rate", out_sample_rate, 0);
av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "in_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);
av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP,  0);
swr_init(swrContext);

memcpy(frame->data[0], data, dataSize); // frame->nb_samples ???

const int out_num_samples = av_rescale_rnd(swr_get_delay(swrContext, in_sample_rate) + frame->nb_samples, out_sample_rate, in_sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);

uint8_t* out_samples = NULL;
av_samples_alloc(&out_samples, NULL, out_num_channels, out_num_samples, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, 0);

out_num_samples = swr_convert(swrContext, &out_samples, out_num_samples, &frame->data[0], frame->nb_samples);

av_freep(&out_samples);    // free after use
swr_free(&swrContext);     // free after use
```

You might want to tinker `out_sample_rate` according to your requirements. I'd suggest converting your file on the command line using `ffmpeg` command and use the parameters that worked in your code later. The code iterations would be less and you'd have more flexibility working on the command line. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus/239356#239356) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854513/can-ffmpeg-convert-audio-to-raw-pcm-if-so-how) thread on using command line `ffmpeg` utility.

Hope this helps!